# How to add quotes in Swal text without being replaced with &quot;?

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

`const sc = {...swalConfig.confirm}; sc.text = "{{ __('Taking the records from the table \"USERS\" to the "ROLES" table, without any additional action.') }}";`

I have this code. But when rendered in browser the \" is shown as &quot;. Any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should embed it as html. Try this:

```
var text = `{!! __('Taking the records from the table \"USERS\" to the \"ROLES\" table, without any additional action.') !!}`;
console.log(text);
```